# DescribeSObjectResult.Fields contains fields that do not appear to exist?

Tags: api, soap-api, fields, describesobject

I am using the force.com SOAP API (Partner WSDL) to query one of our Salesforce orgs and retrieve a list of all objects and all fields of each object.

This seemed pretty simple as I could quite easily retrieve a DescribeGlobalResult object which contained a collection of 'sObjects', I could then call DescribeSObject for each object to retrieve its object representation (an sObject object). Each sObject object contained a collection of Fields, perfect! :D... NO!

Oddly some of the fields contained in the field collections do not appear to exist in the targeted SalesForce org. I guess maybe these fields have been deleted or something(?). Problem I am having is distinguishing which fields actually exist and which ones do not. The Field object does not have a 'Queryable' or 'isDeleted' property. I tried selecting only fields where there byte size was 0 - but then realised what byte size was referring to  :(

If it helps to know why I am trying to do this... I am attempting to build SOQL select all queries, since SOQL does not support * I have to find each field name for each object before building the query. I have done a fair bit of googling and trawling through SF's 'documentation' ... but I have found very little useful info and lot's of pompous PR telling me how great the platform is (descends into frustrated rant).

**NOTE -** Can we please focus on the question of... How to determine if a field exists/has been deleted/can be queried? If this is not possible or I should not be recieving these ghost fields then please say. I am aware of the flaws in the spec and the alternate approaches... I'll save those for a programmers.stackexchange.com/ question :)

**CODE -**

```
    // Please hold off on flaming for the slow, clumsy, non-defensive code - this is just an example
    public void ShowSEMYCode()
    {
        SFAPI.SFConnection sfConn = new Salesforce.API.SFConnection();
        // The above would log me in and convert any exceptions into hateful messages

        // Get global description object which contains a collection of sObjects
        SForce.DescribeGlobalResult globalResult = sfConn.describeGlobal();

        // For each sObject in the collection...
        foreach (SForce.DescribeGlobalSObjectResult globalSObj in globalResult.sobjects)
        {
            // retrieve a DescribeSObjectResult object using SObject name
            SForce.DescribeSObjectResult sObj = sfConn.describeSObject(globalSObj.name);
            List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();

            // For each field ijn sObject.Fields collection....
            foreach (SForce.Field field in sObj.fields)
            {
                // Add its name to my list
                fieldNames.Add(field.name); // I checked - the name proerty seems to be the only property guaranteed to display the API name rather than some friendly name/label.
            }
            // Here i would simply call a method to convert my collection of column names into a SOQL string 
            // (eg: SELECT ColName1, colName2, colNam3__C FROM sObjectName) simples
        }
    }
```

**DescribeSObjectResult class**

```
public DescribeSObjectResult describeSObject(string sObjectType) 
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("describeSObject", new object[] {sObjectType});
    return ((DescribeSObjectResult)(results[0]));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Jamie

**Examples**

```
Object:- Account

  - Id
    - IsDeleted
    - MasterRecordId
    - Name
    - Type
    - RecordTypeId
    - ParentId
    - BillingStreet
    - BillingCity
    - BillingState
    - BillingPostalCode
    - BillingCountry
    - BillingLatitude
    - BillingLongitude
    - ShippingStreet
    - ShippingCity
    - ShippingState
    - ShippingPostalCode
    - ShippingCountry
    - ShippingLatitude  <- Phantom Field!
    - ShippingLongitude
    - Phone
    - Fax
    - Website
  ...
  ...

Object:- Idea

  - Id
    - IsDeleted
    - Title
    - CurrencyIsoCode
    - RecordTypeId
    - CreatedDate
    - CreatedById
    - LastModifiedDate
    - LastModifiedById
    - SystemModstamp
    - LastViewedDate  <- Ghost Field
    - LastReferencedDate
    - CommunityId

Object:- ApexPage

  - Id
    - NamespacePrefix
    - Name
    - ApiVersion
    - MasterLabel
    - Description
    - ControllerType
    - ControllerKey
    - IsAvailableInTouch
    - IsConfirmationTokenRequired <- Duff 
    - Markup
    - CreatedDate
    - CreatedById
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of these phantom fields?

Comment: You can do one thing, permanently delete the fields which are deleted from object

Comment: @JeremyNottingham I do, but I doubt they will be of use to you. An example: xfield__C may be in my sObject field collection, but it is not visible through the Salesforce GUI and when I execute my created SOQL query containing lxfield__C ... I get an error message informing me that xfield__C does not exist :(

Comment: @PramodKumar This would not work for me... or possibly not at all - If the API does not recognise the column when I submit a query, how will I delete the column? I thought this was done via queries (masked behind method calls).

Comment: I would not recommend building select all functionality, your apps will not be performant, and eventually your queries will break when enough fields exist on the object.

Comment: @PhilR Spec says... so I do :)

Comment: High quality.  Can you share your approach?  Building a query based off the field map and `String.join` should do the job.

Comment: @PhilR - haha it is a bit more involved than that - I really do need to 'select all' but yes I understand this will get slower and hit query limits - so does my employer... I added code example if it helps you at all

Comment: Can you provide a Gist link to the generated .Net C# code from the Partner WSDL your using in your app. I suspect for some reason your code is iterating over the fields from the DescribeSObjectResult data type, see here, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#topic-title. I don't have .Net handy so cannot check for you. If you can post the generated code I'll see if I can spot something between that and your code above.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Thanks, that would be great, here is the link 'https://gist.github.com/Jammerz/6164274'. I pulled out the DescribeSObjectResult class code (added the code to question) doesn't seem to be anything in there :/...

Comment: Ok the generated code looks fine against the code your consuming it with in your question above. Can you include a dump of the field.name values your getting in your answer? Double checking the Salesforce SOAP API docs, what you saying is most strange, you should only get existing fields in the fields collection, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#i1427375

Comment: @AndrewFawcett - I only get one error message per attempt (so there could potentially be more that I haven't spotted) - About 90% of the false fields are named lastvieweddate, so I can deal with these by excluding these this field from any queries (but what if a field gets created with this name :s). The remaining 10% are very varied, the only pattern I can spot is that they are all non custom objects (but clearly not standard either). Some examples: billinglatitude, billingprocess, accountid (from a non account related object) , managementTeam (WTF) etc.... it is just weird.

Comment: It is indeed, is the code in your question the code your running? I'm starring at it, and cannot be believe that code is giving you these results. If you try just the code in your answer (as an isolated test from your other code) and put in a console output in the fields loop to dump the object name and field, do you get the same results? If so, i personally think this is a Salesforce support case.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett The above code is just a mock up to show the rough workings of what I am doing - there is a load of other stuff you guys don't need to see... However - running the above code (and dumping object + fields into a dictionary so I can view results) produces exactly the same results - duff fields everywhere!!

Comment: @AndrewFawcett BTW... Just want to say thanks for your help... I do really appreciate it (it's about the only thing keeping me sane right now) :)

Comment: LOL no worries, can you update your question with the exact code you just ran to dump the object + fields and also the dump from the dictionary. I may be able to find a .Net box to try it on, but failing that it will let me double check I don't see anything odd. Suffice to that I am really starting to think this is some kind of bug, buts a hard to believe as its quite fundemental to the entire service the describe operations.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Sure, I have added to GIT to avoid scaring people away with a massive question. GIT has the method shown above and my SFConnection class which logs me in (is more friendly then using the supplied login method). Yeah that is what I thought (I like to blame others first) but after searching what feels like most of the internet (while being followed by SF Google ads!) I have not found a single mention of this 'bug' :| Really stuck for what to next. I suppose I could tweak my code to remove troublesome fields when an error is thrown and then try again - but that is ridiculous!

Comment: Thanks, can you just also add to the GIST the console output, I'm not easily able to run the code (though I do have .Net skills to review it).

Comment: @AndrewFawcett in the example code I am not outputting any info - I just debug and examine the dictionary instances key values. What do you need? An object field model (just a small sample would be very large) or an error output (again above code won't error but it will grab fields I know aren't there).

Comment: Just dump the collection to the console (the standard toString() should giving what your seeing in the debugger). If you can limit it to the one object your having an issue with.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Just added Console.WriteLine's to output. Added changes to GIST and also add an example of my output. I think its becoming clear that there is not really a way to check if a field actually exists... because all returned fields SHOULD exist :/ Can't really see any pattern in the duff fields other than they are all standard fields/ are not appended with __c

Comment: @AndrewFawcett - Comments are getting gigantic - let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10028/discussion-between-jammerz858-and-andrew-fawcett)

Answer (score 5):

From a general stand point, salesforce.com advises against querying more fields than you need due to performance issues, not to mention that there is an upper limit on the maximum size of a query.

That aside, sometimes you do need all fields, because you're exporting, migrating, deduplicating, or many other reasons. Usually, though, it would be better to split the functionality into two calls (for performance reasons): (1) `select id from sourceobject where ...`, then (2) `retrieve(sourceobject, queryresultids, fields)`.

Regardless, using one API call or two, you still need to know which fields are which. This is where `isAccessible` comes into play. When you describe an object, each field that the user can currently access will have `isAccessible` set to true. When false, the user can't query against that field.

ShippingLatitude, by the way, isn't a phantom field; it is a sub-field of the UI element "shipping address", which has seven fields (street, city, state, postal code, country, latitude, and longitude). The UI is prone to showing some fields as a single field set, in particular address fields. You can't see it in the UI/setup screen, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Assuming the user has "read" access to "Shipping Address", they will have access to the seven fields mentioned previously.

If your query is failing, check the field level security for the address field in the UI. Most likely, you'll find that the "field" is hidden, disabling all of those fields. Even system administrators can't violate field level visibility, so be sure that it is set appropriately. Administrators can describe all fields, however, which is why it is misleading to assume that just because a describe shows a field as available means the administrator has permission to query it.

Comment: I'm using the SOAP API and can confirm that I don't have the "isAccessible" property when describing an object and traversing through it's fields.